# How can I fix my NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java, exception

I've tried many different ways to fix the error. I know it has something to do with the hasNext, I'm just not sure where the error is. Please help. Also if someone could tell me how I can get the value of the variable largestQuantity into the main method from my getLargestQuantityItem method I'd appreciate that. Cheers!

Here is the input file that is a .txt file:

```
The Shawshank Redemption
100
19.95
DVD
The Dark Knight
50
19.95
DVD
Casablanca
137
9.95
DVD
The Girl With The Dragon Tattoo
150
14.95
Book
Vertigo
55
9.95
DVD
A Game of Thrones
100
8.95
Book
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Project01 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> Titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Types = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Double> Prices = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Integer> Quantities = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int count = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String database = getFile(in);
    try {
        File file = new File(database);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Product Summary Report");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            getTitle(Titles, inputFile.nextLine());
            getQuantity(Quantities, inputFile.nextInt());
            getPrice(Prices, inputFile.nextDouble());
            getType(Types, inputFile.next());
            System.out.println("Title: " + Titles.get(count));
            System.out.println(" Product Type: " + Types.get(count));
            System.out.println(" Price: " + Prices.get(count));
            System.out.println(" Quantity: " + Quantities.get(count));
            System.out.println();
            count++;
            inputFile.next();
        }
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Total products in database: " + count);
        System.out.println("Largest quantity item: " + largestQuantity);
        System.out.println("Highest total dollar item: ");
        System.out.println("Smallest quantity item: ");
        System.out.println("Lowest total dollar item: ");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
        inputFile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There was a problem reading from " + database);
    }
    in.close();
}
private static String getFile(Scanner inScanner) {
    System.out.print("Enter database filename: ");
    String fileName = inScanner.nextLine();
    return fileName;
}
private static void getTitle(ArrayList<String> Titles, String title) {
    Titles.add(title);
}
private static void getType(ArrayList<String> Types, String type) {
    Types.add(type);
}
private static void getPrice(ArrayList<Double> Prices, double price) {
    Prices.add(price);
}
private static void getQuantity(ArrayList<Integer> Quantities, int quantity) {
    Quantities.add(quantity);
}
private static void getLargestQuantityItem(ArrayList<Integer> Quantities){
    Integer largestQuantity = Collections.max(Quantities);
    }
}
```

Here is the output and the error I'm receiving:

```
Enter database filename: 

Product Summary Report

------------------------------------------------------------
Title: The Shawshank Redemption
 Product Type: DVD
 Price: 19.95
 Quantity: 100

Title:  Dark Knight
 Product Type: DVD
 Price: 19.95
 Quantity: 50

Title: 
 Product Type: DVD
 Price: 9.95
 Quantity: 137

Title:  Girl With The Dragon Tattoo
 Product Type: Book
 Price: 14.95
 Quantity: 150

Title: 
 Product Type: DVD
 Price: 9.95
 Quantity: 55

Title:  Game of Thrones
 Product Type: Book
 Price: 8.95
 Quantity: 100

java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1347)
    at Project01.main(Project01.java:31)
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your code and also provide your stack trace.

Comment: You check `hasNext()` once, but in the loop you get multiple items - any one of those could fail - your stack trace should tell you exactly which on has...

Comment: In your catch block add `e.printStackTrace();` and then execute it once again and review the stack trace.

Comment: What is your file that you pass in?

Comment: Change the return type and return the integer into the main method (where you call it from)

Comment: Seems your input file has a problem. Can u please attach it?

Comment: Hmm, I've never used a stacktrace. I did what @NamanGala said to do but it didn't show a stacktrace after execution.

Comment: Can you change `IOException` to `Exception` in catch block and run it once again.

Comment: @Diluu I added the input file's contents. I'm not sure how to attach a file.

Comment: @NamanGala I did that just now and it still isn't showing a stacktrace. I'll edit the post to include my output after execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/3898076) post and your txt file.

Add `inputFile.nextLine()` after your `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()` method.

```
getQuantity(Quantities, inputFile.nextInt());
inputFile.nextLine();
getPrice(Prices, inputFile.nextDouble());
inputFile.nextLine();
```

Change below code

```
getType(Types, inputFile.nextLine());
```

And remove your `inputFile.next();` at the end of your while loop.

**Second approach** will be just add if block around your `next();` method call.

```
if (inputFile.hasNext()) {
    inputFile.next();
}
```

The problem was that `next();` at the end of the while loop was reading the next element. But at the end of file after `Book` there was nothing to read so it was throwing Exception at that line.

**Update:**

`largestQuantity` is a local variable, it can not be accessed outside the method. You should return it from `getLargestQuantityItem` method. So change the return type of your method and then return the max value.

```
private static Integer getLargestQuantityItem(ArrayList<Integer> Quantities){
    return Collections.max(Quantities);
}
```

And in main method

To get Largest quantity item:

```
System.out.println("Lowest total dollar item: ");
Integer largestQuantityMainVariable = getLargestQuantityItem(Quantities);
System.out.println("Largest quantity : " + largestQuantityMainVariable);

int index;
for (int i = 0; i < Quantities.size(); i++) {
    if (Quantities.get(i) != null && Quantities.get(i).equals(largestQuantityMainVariable)) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println("Largest quantity item : " + Titles.get(index));
```

**Update 2:**

For the question in the comments `The only thing I have left is to find the highest and lowest total dollar value. I need to somehow take the quantity times the price and then look for the max and min value out of those values`

```
private static List<Double> generateTotalPriceList(List<Double> prices, List<Integer> quantities) {
    List<Double> totalPriceList = null;
    if (prices != null && prices.size() > 0
            && quantities != null && quantities.size() > 0) {
        if (prices.size() == quantities.size()) {
            totalPriceList = new ArrayList<Double>();
            double totalValue;
            for (int i = 0; i < prices.size(); i++) {
                totalValue = prices.get(i) * (double) quantities.get(i);
                totalPriceList.add(totalValue);
            }
        }
    }
    return totalPriceList;
}
```

In main method

```
List<Double> totalPriceList = generateTotalPriceList(Prices, Quantities);
```

Now you can follow the procedure as we did for `Quantity`.

Comment: So when dealing with a double list you have to use (double) list.get(i) for the index? That was one of the things giving me trouble.

Comment: if you don't put `(double)` then also it is not giving any compilation error. You can check the output with or without (double).